# Modern authentication implementation in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, authentication

I'm creating SpringBoot application and I'm investigating how to handle modern authorization and authentication process. In future I would like to authenticate users via facebook/google. Should I use spring libraries only or I should search for any external services like Firebase?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion spring boot is more thant enough, in this great ecosystem we have a lot of possibilities. Here in your current case and next ones, spring-boot provide a starters that make our development experience more beautiful.
I think you will chose oAuth2.0/2.1 with Oidc Connect.
In this case we have

[Client-Side](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/client/index.html),

[Resource Server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/index.html),

[Authorization Server](https://spring.io/projects/spring-authorization-server)

But if you don't want to write your own oAuth server, you can use open source project(keycloack) just run, configure and integrate your system with them.